# Center modal horizontally without jquery

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a modal in a react app, the `width` is set to auto and the `position` is `fixed`, I am trying to get it centered in the middle of the screen horizontally.

```
.Modal {
    position:fixed; 
    width: auto;
    z-index: 500;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.889);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

I have tried a few of the solutions that come up in stack overflow when searching to center the modal.

The main issue I am having is that this modal is above other elements on the `z-index` and if I change the `position` to `absolute`, as most of the examples suggest, the items that have been rendered below it on the `z-index` get shifted down the screen.

This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `margin:0 auto;` to your css and remove position:fixed.

Comment: After adding that the modal is still pinned to the left hand side of the window.

Comment: Please try to add your code to jsfiddle, we can debug there.

Comment: Also, remove the fixed position

Answer (score 1):

Adding "margin: 0 auto;" is not going to work on a item with position: fixed.

Either lose the position fixed and do margin: 0 auto;

Or
Set the left position on (50% - width element / 2).

But i guess the first solution is the easiest one.

Answer (score 1):

because your modal is position fixed, you need to use left or right css properties to change the horizontal position of your modal. But you have 'width' auto, which will not work because the width can vary. The easiest way would be to wrap the modal in a parent div, like the following

```css
.modal-parent {
  position: fixed; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  top: 0;  
  left: 0;  
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal {
  padding: 40px; 
  background: white; 
}
```

```html
<div class='modal-parent'>
  <div class='modal'>

  </div>
</div>
```

or if you don't want a parent div, you can just give it a static width, and the height can vary:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed; 
  padding: 40px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;  
  left: calc(50% - 150px);  
  width: 300px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class='modal'>

</div>
```